# Disable/Deactivate file preview on shared/published files in Alfresco

Tags: share, alfresco, publish, preview

I want to fully disable the preview of any kind of file for shared/published files in Alfresco.

```
    Alfresco Community v4.2.0
    (r56674-b4848) schema 6033

    Spring Surf and Spring WebScripts - v1.2.0
    (Release 1331)
```

In Alfresco, you are able to share/publish any kind of file. By sharing/publishing the file, you will get a link to access this shared file. Other users like clients/customers for example are able to view the shared/published file and can download it via a link like this:

```
    https://alfresco.example.com/share/s/9QJiV6PNSAqAlxZDnFVQlQ
```

My problem is, that I hate this preview regarding some browser and preview display issues. Some kind of files like ZIP-files aren't able to be displayed in the preview and this causes an empty preview, which sometime causes an missing download button.

I also just don't want the preview. Well, how can I disable/deactivate the whole preview (only) for shared/published files, that the preview does not appear, if I visit the share-link?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Override in web-extension **alfresco/site-data/pages/quickshare.xml**

And remove the **sub-component** with id `web-preview`

BTW: you know if you disable the preview users won't have any ability to download or view the file.

Comment: Please, what?! How can I change the page, that users are still able to download the file without displaying the preview?

Comment: I hope, we are talking about the same preview. I mean this big grey preview box: http://i.imgur.com/autfuwW.png It contains the text "The preview can not be loaded from the server.". And if this occurs, I am NOT able to download this file.

Comment: It's not the preview which restricts downloading a file, you just need to 'add' a download file button. Take a look here: http://www.contentreich.de/the-missing-alfresco-quickshare-download

Comment: Thx, the contentreich.de plugin was a nice solution!